# Delete Cause for not Downvoted Question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

First time I read this question:
[Is a stored procedure with a single statement worth it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48086357/is-a-stored-procedure-with-a-single-statement-worth-it)

[image]

I was inclined to delete it. I thought to myself: It's plain dumb because there's not much
difference if a SP got 1 line or a hundred. Later talking with aspiring developers I realized it's
a valid concern for less experienced developers and found code encapsulation is "sold" as a sort of bag
where one can "placehold" a **lot** of code for a function/subroutine/procedure name.

So I got back to the question and answered it. Not surprise it got a couple of "close the question" votes but I
left the judgment for the community. If it got enough downvotes so it deserves to be closed.
(my bad I don't asked OP for clarification on why he thinks one line don't deserves a SP).

But after a week the question don't got enough donwvotes and for my surprise my answer got four upvotes (neat).

A couple of days passes and the question was deleted. I was surprised because I don't see a good justification for deleting a question/answer got
a net four upvotes (I really think OP can clarify it a bit tought).

So I read again about [**Why and how are some questions deleted?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions) and don't see a good motive to keep it deleted.

So I humble ask what was justification to delete it?

Comment: *Lack of upvotes* is an indication of quality too

Comment: I don't have enough rep to see the question but from then title alone I would guess _primarily opinion-based_

Comment: ... *opinion based* &/or *too broad* - Take your pick

Comment: The question from the picture looks like something that can be "rescued" by an edit to something like "Are there any advantages, like performance, by moving a regularly executed Update query into a stored procedure?". But I wonder if that hasn't been asked before. Looks like a question which is quite basic and therefore has a high chance of being a dupe.

Comment: @Tom How does that edit fix any of the problems?

Comment: That would not make the question any more narrow or not POB. Questions have to be **specific**. Once a correct answer would contain something like "it depends", the question can be considered too broad (or POB, depending on the exact wording).

Comment: @Tom That was my first guess but don't found dupe because it's really a basic question but one not addressed on books or tutorials. The question here IMHO is "It's worth to create a SP even for a minimal code?" and the asnwers can be "quantity of code is not very relevant, consider the broad stuff"

Comment: The question was originally closed as *primarily opinion-based* and I would also consider it as being too broad. as such it was also drawing a lot of opinion based answers. Yet with 5 answers none saw it fit to up-vote the question either.

Comment: @Nkosi I can accept caliing it a dupe (if OP not specific asked if it's worth even for a single statement query) but using or not a SP brings specific advantages and disvantages thus I cannot call it a opnion based more than listing the pros and cons and let OP decide over using or not SP

Comment: To quote: `Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.`

Comment: @Nkosi to quote upvoted answer: ".. the SP will be compiled once and it can save CPU for a query being executed many times every hour.." it's not opnion based it's a FACT based on specific expertise. That's I saying the answers are fact based more than opnion based

Comment: "*So I read again about [Why and how are some questions deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions) and don't see a good motive to keep it deleted.*" ― this document is not even supposed to give an answer to a question **why** community deletes questions ― it only states the fact "*Questions can also be deleted by the community.*" Why do you refer to this document to prove something that it isn't even talking about?

Comment: Regarding the title "*Delete Cause for not Downvoted Question*" ― you might not yet have discovered, but highly upvoted questions+answers require more votes to delete than three (and there are lots of them getting deleted). If the only criterion was whether the question was downvoted ― why would such a mechanism even exist on SO?

Comment: @techraf The donwvotes/upvotes is a good mechanism to separate usefull from less usefull posts. If the question got donwvoted I can agree to delete it but it don't and the answers got upvoted so it means a few guys actually found it usefull, my concerns is: are we deleting usefull content?

Comment: That's not what I asked you about. I asked **why** SO implemented a mechanism to increase the number of required delete-votes in case of highly upvoted questions+answers.　・　You imply upvoted q+a's should not be deleted at all. SO implemented mechanism clearly allowing that (and the requirement for higher number of del-votes shows that was intentional). Don't you see a discrepancy here?

Comment: My personal view had nothing to do with the number of answers/votes up/downvotes. The question itself was broad and primarily opinion based and not a good fit for SO so I voted for deletion.

Comment: Also usefulness doesn't mean that a question isn't still unsuitable for SO. For instance it may well be useful to have a post with links to a list of recommended books but it's still off-topic even though it's useful for some users

Comment: This question [great-programming-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640/great-programming-quotes) has 554 upvotes (net 530) and is deleted. This is just to state that there is no direct relation between votes and if community decide to delete it or not.

Comment: @techraf Guy I just asked for clarification =). Alas this question ended being a good example of what I'm talking about. I'm not experienced with moderation questions and this was elucidative to me but most downvoted considering it dumb now let's wait for the close voted to waste a good answer ;). Note: i's it a opnion based question?

Comment: No, it was **I** who asked you for a clarification of your question. That's what comments under the question are for.　・　You prepared your storyline "non-downvoted question deleted for a reason not present in the [Why and how are some questions deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions).　・　I am asking how these two arguments relate to the case.

Comment: *to be honest it was not community that decided to delete that question but one of the founder of SE, Jeff, but yeah I guess he likes us to follow his lead*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is likely have answer already, potentially asking for tutorial, looking for unbounded list of differences or simply seeking discussion. While it is remarkable to fit so many reasons to close the question in one paragraph it does not make it on-topic for SO.

State before deletion clearly shows that people like to put their  2 cents into discussion and add some answers (5 "it depends" answers). As result if kept around this question would serve for future "why you @#$#$@ closed my question as too broad when that one is so popular" complains.

Note that answers to the linked question mostly re-hash [What is a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459457/what-is-a-stored-procedure) which would be good duplicate. If OP carefully read that they could have edited the question to make it specific to make post on-topic and hence potentially get re-opened.

Comment: At least some reasoning! The tricky part is **"it depends"** is a necessary mantra for most SQL answers. For example for the question I'm inclined to answer YES do it but so there are considerations about sniffing, "ALWAYS_RECOMPILE" option, code maintenance and production deployment. Things someone stated not intimacy with SQL must be learn about before making a decision